# Parsing a value from a DateTimePicker gives "not a valid Datetime" error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetimepicker

`txtDOP` is a DateTimePicker in ASP.NET form

```
DateTime idop = DateTime.Parse(txtDOP.Text);
```

> The error is not a valid Datetime

In local host it is running fine but in webserver it is giving error.

Comment: Check your regional settings on the control panel, is the date format on localhost different to that on the web server?

Comment: What is the value of `txtDOP.Text` ?

Comment: the value of txtdop is 15/05/2013

Comment: That value isn't a valid date in many regions, but since a `DateTimePicker`'s `Value` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) is a `DateTime` anyway, why are you trying to parse the text value?